# Augmented Reality framework for sending to a video

Tags: android, image, video, augmented-reality

I am new to Augmented Reality, and I was wondering if there was already an existing Framework available for my situation. I want to make an App that scans a non coded image (bottle, pen, phone etc.), and based on the image, sends the user to a specific video.

Is there anything like this currently available? I think this would be more marker based, but I am not entirely sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [this](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality) in my app. I found it pretty easy and it did good work in my app. Its Motorola's augmented reality framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this if you only want a video to show up when an image is tracked: https://dev.metaio.com/creator/getting-started/
you just drag the video you want over the image you want to trigger it and then deploy it.

If you'd prefer to actually code it within a framework, you can try the metaio sdk, which also allows you use 3D objects for tracking-- i.e you said track an image of a pen, but why not track the pen itself? Tutorials and more info here: 
metaio sdk tutorial: https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/
3D object tracking tool: https://dev.metaio.com/toolbox/